# Return all rows that match column 1 of a row selected by criteria in column 2

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

Unfortunately, I think I'm quite limited in what solutions I can apply. I'm doing this for work and I only have permissions to SELECT from tables through Access 2010. I can't update or create tables. I can't find useful information like what version of sql is on the backend, let alone access the database directly or use VBA.

Say we have a dataset like this (crude looking, sorry):

```
MemberID   |  StatusCd   |  Date Added
12345      |  200        | 08/01/2016
12345      |  300        | 09/01/2016
12345      |  400        | 10/01/2016
5646       |  400        | 10/01/2016
8946       |  100        | 07/01/2016
```

Now, this database is massive and it'll be a huge performance issue if I try to pull all members in the table and process it afterwards. What I want is to return all rows that share a MemberID where at least one row for that MemberID is StatusCd 300. For instance, if I wanted information about members that hit Status 300, the desired table would look like:

```
MemberID   |  StatusCd   |  Date Added
12345      |  200        | 08/01/2016
12345      |  300        | 09/01/2016
12345      |  400        | 10/01/2016
```

However, right now when I try use a SELECT command that uses WHERE StatusCd = 300, I only get the one row where that condition is met. I don't know if it will interfere with anything, but I'm currently joining this table to another table on the memberID to get a smaller, more relevant table set to work with. It would also be nice to omit rows that come prior to the StatusCd 300, but that's a small chunk of extra data that won't hurt too much to leave in.

Thanks for any help anybody can provide!

Edit: adjusted phrasing based on comment feedback.

Comment: Question is not very clear, All rows for a member where at least 1 row has a statuscd of 300? `select * from t where memberid in (select memberid from t where statuscd=300)`

Comment: Right, just as you said. I'll see if I can update the wording, then I'll give that a try. I'm really new to SQL so I didn't even know you could nest selects like that.

Comment: Wow, that did the trick! I don't know why I didn't consider the possibility that I can use SELECT to return values like I would with a function in another language. Now that I know that I'll see if I can play around with the dates to get something meaningful. If you add your comment as an answer, I'll be happy to credit you for answering my question.

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

To get all rows for a member where at least 1 row has a `statuscd` of 300 first select all the corresponding `memberid` with a sub-query then select everything with that `memberid` from the table:

```
select * 
from t 
where memberid in (
   select memberid from t where statuscd = 300
)
```